# ¿Por qué en mi input no sale bien el valor que le ingrese?

Tags: javascript, html5

[image: Imagen en donde sale separado el valor]

Estoy recibiendo los datos para poder mostrarlos en un formulario por medio de JS entonces cuando inserto en el input la variable cuando recargo y veo el resultado me aparece mocho el nombre y lo revise en consola y si viene completo pero en el input no aparece bien, saben algo hacerca del porque me aparece asi?.
Les dejo el pedazo de codigo de como lo inserto al input gracias.

```js
"<div class='col-sm-3'>"+
                                "<label for='nombresTrabajadorActualizar' class='form-label'>Nombres del trabajador</label>"+
                                "<div class='input-group mb-3'>"+
                                    "<span class='input-group-text' id='basic-addon1'><i class='bx bxs-edit-alt'></i></span>"+
                                    "<input type='text' class='form-control' aria-describedby='basic-addon1' name='nombresTrabajadorActualizar' id='nombresTrabajadorActualizar' value="+nombreTrabajador+" disabled>"+
                                "</div>"+
                            "</div>"+
```

Comment: Te faltan comillas simples antes y después de concatenar con la variable, prueba con `value='"+nombreTrabajador+"'`.

Answer (score 0):

Porque estás asignando mal el valor, tienes que incluir unas comillas así:

```js
"<div class='col-sm-3'>"+
                                "<label for='nombresTrabajadorActualizar' class='form-label'>Nombres del trabajador</label>"+
                                "<div class='input-group mb-3'>"+
                                    "<span class='input-group-text' id='basic-addon1'><i class='bx bxs-edit-alt'></i></span>"+
                                    "<input type='text' class='form-control' aria-describedby='basic-addon1' name='nombresTrabajadorActualizar' id='nombresTrabajadorActualizar' value='"+nombreTrabajador+"' disabled>"+
                                "</div>"+
                            "</div>"+
```

Comment: cierto se me habia olvidado por estar haciendolo rapido no puse atención en eso, muchas gracias, necesita una opinion diferente a la de mi cabeza porque no podia ver porque me salia asi, te agradezco amigo, un saludo.